# Solr Sort by Title using solarium

Tags: sorting, solr, solarium

I try to sort by title ascending using solr and Solarium.
I do this

```
$query->addSort('title', $query::SORT_ASC);
```

But it returns 500 whereas this

```
$query->addSort('itcreation_dateem_id', $query::SORT_ASC);
```

succeeds. How is it possible to do the sorting of title?

Comment: Is your title a string or a number? Coz am assuming itcreation_dateem_id is of type number.

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, the Solr log will tell you why. My guess is that the field type of `title` is not sortable. In addition, to sort by a string, you really want a non-analyzed field type (so not `text`, as that's analyzed and tokenized).